# Turn off in app sounds in facebook

Tags: facebook

How do I turn off in-app sounds in facebook for android 397.0.0.23.404?

There seems to be no section named "media and contacts" in the settings menu.

As a result, every time I push a like button, I get a disturbing sound from the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Facebook app (400.0.37.76)

In the Facebook app, you can follow these items to find "Sounds in the app":

- Tap the "Hamburger menu" (three lines) in the top right from the main page
- Tap the "gear" for settings in the top right
- Tap "Profile settings" (with your name and photo next to it)
- Scroll down and select "Media and contacts"
- Disable the toggle for "Sounds in the app"

For what it's worth, the "Media and contacts" section also showed up for me when searching in settings for "sound"

Screenshots for help:

### Hamburger menu

[image: Hamburger menu]

### Settings gear

[image: Settings gear]

### Profile settings

[image: Profile settings]

### Media and contacts

[image: Media and contacts]

### Sounds in the app

[image: Sounds in the app]

## Facebook Messenger

In the settings of the Messenger app, tap your profile picture in the top-left to get to the settings menu. From there, select "Notifications & sounds", then turn off the "In-app sounds" toggle:

[image: Notifications & sounds]

[image: In-app sounds toggle]